# How to protect vector from resizing?

Tags: vector, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

So I am going through Practical Common Lisp once again and I cannot really understand how to create a vector with constant size.

According to the book:

> However, even a vector with a fill pointer isn't completely resizable. The vector *x* can hold at most five elements. To make an arbitrarily resizable vector, you need to pass MAKE-ARRAY another keyword argument: :adjustable.

However when I use `(vector-push-extend)` I can extend my initial vector even when I set `:adjustable nil` (or leave it default).

```
(vector-push 'a *x*) ;; 0
(vector-push 'b *x*) ;; 1
(vector-push 'c *x*) ;; 2
(vector-push 'd *x*) ;; 3
(vector-push 'e *x*) ;; 4
*x* ;; #(A B C D E)
(vector-push 'f *x*) ;; NIL
*x* ;; #(A B C D E)
(vector-push-extend 'f *x*) ;; 5
*x* ;; #(A B C D E F)
```

I assumed that `(vector-push-extend)` cannot resize array which is not `:adjustable`? What is the correct way of creating non-dynamic (non-adjustable) array?

Comment: which implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using SBCL 1.5.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is implementation specific.

The Common Lisp specification says:

> There is no specified way to create an array for which adjustable-array-p definitely returns false.

An implementation may make vectors adjustable, even though the `:adjustable` argument to `make-array` is given as `nil`.

To see if an array object is *actually* adjustable, one needs to call `adjustable-array-p`.

The Common Lisp standard says that a vector is *expressly adjustable* (and thus also *actually adjustable* if it was requested to be so. If it wasn't request, the vector can still be *adjustable*, *actually adjustable*.

So the `:adjustable nil` arg is just telling Lisp, that it can make the vector non-adjustable, if possible.

Here in SBCL:

1) A normal vector is not adjustable:

```
* (make-array 5)
#(0 0 0 0 0)
* (adjustable-array-p *)
NIL
```

2) A vector with a fill-pointer is *actually adjustable* in SBCL:

```
* (make-array 5 :fill-pointer 0)
#()
* (adjustable-array-p *)
T
```

3) A vector with a fill-pointer is *actually adjustable* in SBCL, even though the `:adjustable` arg was given as `nil`:

```
* (make-array 5 :fill-pointer 0 :adjustable nil)
#()
* (adjustable-array-p *)
T
```

That's in SBCL. In LispWorks 2) and 3) would not be actually adjustable.

Answer (score 6):

The specification of `make-array` says that it is implementation dependent whether an array with `:adjustable nil` is *actually adjustable*.  In the notes, it goes on to say:

> There is no specified way to create an array for which adjustable-array-p definitely returns false.

So, it really depends on the implementation.

The correct way is to use `vector-push` if you do not want to extend.